# SSH and web interface broken on Yun

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, ssh

I have two Arduino Yuns that are not accessible *at all* on the network. I can't go to the arduinoname.local, ssh arduinoname.local, as I previously could. I know at least one it working because it sends emails as I programmed it, yet it seems there is no longer a way to ssh into it. Any ideas?

Yes, I have unplugged, plugged in the router,  and the yuns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is a fairly common one - Actiontec wireless access points break this way when set to Both, not AES - see https://superuser.com/questions/522781/unable-to-ssh-from-any-wireless-ip-to-another-wireless-ip-on-home-network

Apparently on other routers this bug is marked as a feature, "Wireless Isolation" or something.